# How does QIODevice::readLine(qint64 maxSize = 0) works?

Tags: c++, qt, readline, behavior, qbytearray

The [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#readLine) of this method states:

> **QByteArray QIODevice::readLine(qint64 maxSize = 0)**
> This is an overloaded function.
> Reads a line from the device, but no more than maxSize characters, and returns the result as a byte array.

However, I notice that even if we pass `maxSize = 0`, viz. don't pass anything, the `readLine()` sends several bytes in the line. Is this a well defined behaviour?

Besides, here is one decade old issue on the same topic: [QIODevice::readLine(qint64 maxSize = 0) default argument performs poorly (should be documented)](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-7807). Is this still relevant?

Comment: My guess would be, `maxSize == 0` is a special value that means "no limit". It wouldn't have made sense to make 0 the default value if it meant "don't read anything at all". It's unfortunate that the documentation doesn't clarify this.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik you are correct (and Qt people should fix their API documentation!) -- at qiodevice.cpp, line 1466 we have this:  `if (maxSize == 0) maxSize = MaxByteArraySize - 1;`

Comment: @JeremyFriesner or Igor, please post this as an answer, I will accept it. Even the subquestion can be easy to answer, if you have seen the source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not mentioned in the Qt API documentation, but passing in a value of 0 as the `maxSize` argument is treated as having a special meaning of "as many bytes as possible".  Evidence of that intent can be seen at line 1466 of the qiodevice.cpp source file in Qt:

```
if (maxSize == 0) maxSize = MaxByteArraySize - 1;
```